# Difference between "don't have + noun" and "don't have any + noun"

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, phrase-usage

In negative sentences, what is the difference between the forms "*don't have + noun*" and "*don't have any + noun*"?

Here are two couples of examples:

(With countable nouns)

> 1. *I don’t have books*
> 2. *I don’t have any books*

(With uncountable nouns)

> 3. *I don’t have sugar*
> 4. *I don’t have any sugar*

Is one of each pair correct and not the other? Or is Is one of each pair idiomatic and not the other?
In case both forms are correct, when should I use one? And when should I use the other?

Answer (score 1):

They're both fine. In such contexts, ***any*** is usually just an optional "intensifier" - which can be further emphasized by giving the word extra stress...

> 1: *Will you please stop asking to borrow a few pounds? I already told you, I don't have **any** money!*

---

But there can be another significant difference in meaning. Consider...

> 2: *I don't have alcohol in my house*
>   3: *I don't have any alcohol in my house*
>   4: *I have no alcohol in my house*

As a native speaker, I'd normally understand #2 as implying *I don't **allow** alcohol in my house* (so don't try to bring any in), but I wouldn't normally distinguish between #3 and #4. Mostly, they'd probably just mean *If we want to continue drinking at my house, we'd better buy some alcohol to take back, because I haven't got any*.

It's just possible I might prefer #4 (*without* with intensifying ***any***) if I knew I had some long-ignored sickly liqueur at the back of the drinks cabinet. But probably not - native speakers aren't usually *that* precise about how we express the negative in such contexts.